# Is there anyway to retrieve certain column from a dataset extracted from linear regression in r?

Tags: mysql, r

I would need to plot a graph against its performance with its coefficient i got from linear regression.

```
#linear regression
results <- lm(quality ~ receive_menu + order_taking + 
              receive_food + cleanliness + food_quality +
              responsiveness + bill, data = rs)
```

For my Y axis i am already able to get the mean of every variable which will be used as my Y in plot()

```
> y
  receive_menu   order_taking   receive_food    cleanliness   food_quality responsiveness 
      7.601476       7.447724       7.378844       7.712177       7.629766       7.564576 
          bill 
      7.863469
```

However for my x, i need to use the coefficients from the linear regression.

when i use x = results$coefficients , i will have one more column of (intercept) and i cant plot graph as x and y have different length.

```
   (Intercept)   receive_menu   order_taking   receive_food    cleanliness   food_quality 
     5.6116323      1.1756895      2.0083898      0.7870463      0.8947121      1.4160122 
responsiveness           bill 
     1.7761529      0.5307011
```

I tried to remove the specific variable from the "results" which i get from using the linear regression

```
df3 <- results[,c("receive_menu","order_taking","receive_food","cleanliness","food_quality","responsiveness","bill")]
```

However i get the error:

```
Error in results[, c("receive_menu", "order_taking", "receive_food", "cleanliness",  : 
  incorrect number of dimensions
```

Comment: How can y have the names? Those names are columns of X. there is only one name of y which is `quality` so what do you mean by `receive_menu` in y??

Comment: Do you want, `df3 <- results$coef[c("receive_menu","order_taking","receive_food","cleanliness","food_quality","responsiveness","bill")]`

Comment: yes! thats was the it! thanks a lot!